# Switch between open windows in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

After search in the nautilus shortcut description:

[image]

I searched in the [forums](http://forum.world.st/Keyboard-shortcuts-td3084291.html) to find something about this, but doesn't work in Pharo v3.

I still looking for a shortcut that I can use to easily change between open windows such as alt + tab/cmd + tab in a SO.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Nautilus is just a tool for browsing code, so what you get is logically a description of shortcuts local to this tool...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is work in progress. Right now, it seems that the key combination has not yet been decided/implemented.
When I explore the key mapping attached to the world,

```
World kmDispatcher explore.
```

I only see CMD+K reported as part of directKeymaps bound to `[ self openAndCommitToMonticello ]`.
If I browse senders of `openAndCommitToMonticello`, I discover some incantation:

```
Komitter class>>initialize
    World 
        bindKeyCombination: $k command
        toAction: [ self openAndCommitToMonticello ]
```

Apparently, CMD+K must be understood as lowercase $k... (?)

The message for navigating thru windows is `SystemWindow class>>sendTopWindowToBack` (don't ask how I discoverd this...).
There are two senders

1. the old keymapping infrastructure `PasteUpMorph>>defaultDesktopCommandKeyTriplets`
2. A window menu (triggered by upper right down triangle)  `WorldState class>>windowsOn:`

It seems the assigned key was \... So we can try and hook this key binding again.
Since it is rather not convenient on my French mac keyboard (CMD+\ means holding four keys !!!), I'll do it with right arrow.

If you look at `KMSingleKeyCombination class>>specialKeys`, you see that code for right arrow is 29.

So let's try this:

```
World 
    bindKeyCombination: 29 command
    toAction: [ System sendTopWindowToBack ].
```

Et voila, you get a new shortcut for navigating.

Comment: Is almost perfect.
In the last version (Pharo 3 betha) worsks for me use:

```[SystemWindow sendTopWindowToBack]. 

instead of:
 
```[ System sendTopWindowToBack ].

Comment: Thanks, I got a working solution from this answer for making a global keyboard shortcut, though I don't understand why. When I inspect `World`, I don't see the method `bindKeyCombination`. Where is that defined?

Comment: @mydoghasworms which Pharo version? Pharo is evolving fast. It is 7.0 nowadays...

Comment: @aka.nice Sorry, yes, Pharo 7.0. However, I just looked again and see it is a method selector in Morph. Does that mean it only works as a global shortcut on any new windows opened after I set this? I.e. the event is handled by whatever Morph has focus, right?

Answer (score 6):

From Denis Kudriashov on the Pharo Slack,

https://github.com/juliendelplanque/Mirage

provides ergonomic support in Pharo 5.0.

Loadable from the Catalog.

Comment: This is absolutely great! I also confirm that it works with Pharo 5.0. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Pharo 3.0 - Alt+tab works fine (continuously pressing it will keep flipping through windows, and pressing enter or space will select the displayed window)